# Initialize Multiple Numpy Arrays (Multiple Assignment) - Like MATLAB deal()

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, initialization, variable-assignment

I was unable to find anything describing how to do this, which leads to be believe I'm not doing this in the proper idiomatic Python way.  Advice on the 'proper' Python way to do this would also be appreciated.

I have a bunch of variables for a datalogger I'm writing (arbitrary logging length, with a known maximum length).  In MATLAB, I would initialize them all as 1-D arrays of zeros of length n, n bigger than the number of entries I would ever see, assign each individual element `variable(measurement_no) = data_point` in the logging loop, and trim off the extraneous zeros when the measurement was over.  The initialization would look like this:

```
[dData gData cTotalEnergy cResFinal etc] = deal(zeros(n,1));
```

Is there a way to do this in Python/NumPy so I don't either have to put each variable on its own line:

```
dData = np.zeros(n)
gData = np.zeros(n)
etc.
```

I would also prefer not just make one big matrix, because keeping track of which column is which variable is unpleasant.  Perhaps the solution is to make the `(length x numvars)` matrix, and assign the column slices out to individual variables?

EDIT:  Assume I'm going to have a lot of vectors of the same length by the time this is over; e.g., my post-processing takes each log file, calculates a bunch of separate metrics (>50), stores them, and repeats until the logs are all processed.  Then I generate histograms, means/maxes/sigmas/etc. for all the various metrics I computed.  Since initializing 50+ vectors is clearly not easy in Python, what's the best (cleanest code and decent performance) way of doing this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're really motivated to do this in a one-liner you could create an `(n_vars, ...)` array of zeros, then unpack it along the first dimension:

```
a, b, c = np.zeros((3, 5))
print(a is b)
# False
```

Another option is to use a list comprehension or a generator expression:

```
a, b, c = [np.zeros(5) for _ in range(3)]   # list comprehension
d, e, f = (np.zeros(5) for _ in range(3))   # generator expression
print(a is b, d is e)
# False False
```

Be careful, though! You might think that using the `*` operator on a list or tuple containing your call to `np.zeros()` would achieve the same thing, but it doesn't:

```
h, i, j = (np.zeros(5),) * 3
print(h is i)
# True
```

This is because the expression inside the tuple gets evaluated first. `np.zeros(5)` therefore only gets called once, and each element in the repeated tuple ends up being a reference to the same array. This is the same reason why you can't just use `a = b = c = np.zeros(5)`.

Unless you really need to assign a large number of empty array variables and you really care deeply about making your code compact (!), I would recommend initialising them on separate lines for readability.

Comment: This gets the closest to what I'm trying to do.  In some of my other Matlab code - the stuff used to analyze the output of the data logger - I wind up creating a very large number of vectors to store computed metrics for each run.  They all get initialized as part of a big `deal(zeros(n,1))`, and I prefer to not have to keep track of how many there are on the left side of the assignment.  I rather get the feeling I should use a structure instead, but Matlab's syntax makes this somewhat painful.  See the edit to my question.

Comment: Sorry, you're going to have to keep track of how many variables you're assigning on the LHS yourself. The problem is that in Python the function that's being called has no idea what's going to be done with the return value, so it can't know how many are needed on the LHS. Think of it as the price you pay for having the flexibility to do things like indexing into the result of a function call.

Comment: You might consider using a [`recarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) to keep track of multiple vectors empty vectors of the same length with different 'column names'

Answer (score 5):

Nothing wrong or un-Pythonic with

```
dData = np.zeros(n)
gData = np.zeros(n)
etc.
```

You could put them on one line, but there's no particular reason to do so.

```
dData, gData = np.zeros(n), np.zeros(n)
```

Don't try `dData = gData = np.zeros(n)`, because a change to `dData` changes `gData` (they point to the same object).  For the same reason you usually don't want to use `x = y = []`.

The `deal` in MATLAB is a convenience, but isn't magical.  Here's how Octave implements it

```
function [varargout] = deal (varargin)
  if (nargin == 0)
    print_usage ();
  elseif (nargin == 1 || nargin == nargout)
    varargout(1:nargout) = varargin;
  else
    error ("deal: nargin > 1 and nargin != nargout");
  endif

endfunction
```

In contrast to Python, in Octave (and presumably MATLAB)

```
one=two=three=zeros(1,3)
```

assigns different objects to the 3 variables.

Notice also how MATLAB talks about `deal` as a way of assigning contents of cells and structure arrays.  http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/whats-the-big-deal.html

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this discussion on deal(); I marked the other answer, but I found this one very helpful as well and wish I didn't have to pick just one.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your data in a `collections.defaultdict` you won't need to do any explicit initialization. Everything will be initialized the first time it is used.

```py
import numpy as np
import collections
n = 100
data = collections.defaultdict(lambda: np.zeros(n))
for i in range(1, n):
    data['g'][i] = data['d'][i - 1]
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `map`:

```
import numpy as np
n = 10  # Number of data points per array
m = 3   # Number of arrays being initialised
gData, pData, qData = map(np.zeros, [n] * m)
```