# initialize multiple numpy array efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

I need to initialize multiple numpy arrays with the same shape. Wondering which way is the best to go:

1. write a line for each:

```
dist_x=np.zeros((1,len(pose07)-1))
dist_y=np.zeros((1,len(pose07)-1))
rots_absulute=np.zeros((1,len(pose07)-1))
rots=np.zeros((1,len(pose07)-1))
```

2. calculate the length first and save it as a parameter:

```
length=len(pose07)-1

dist_x=np.zeros(1,length)
dist_y=np.zeros(1,length)
rots_absulute=np.zeros(1,length)
rots=np.zeros(1,length)
```

3. initialize one of them, then copy it multiple times:

```
dist_x=np.zeros((1,len(pose07)-1))
dist_y=np.copy(dist_x)
rots_absulute=np.copy(dist_x)
rots=np.copy(dist_x)
```

or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Haven't timed it, but I think we can reasonably guess that copying will be slower - no need to read in data known to be zeros, compared to just writing zeros.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860276/11667949

Comment: Consider `np.empty_like` or `np.zeros_like`.  At least it looks cleaner. If you know for sure that you're going to overwrite all elements, `np.empty` can be faster than `np.zeros`, depending on whether it's memory allocated via the operating system or re-used memory that was already allocated by the process.

Comment: It depends on your definition of *"better"*. It's unlikely you mean speed because any halfway decent algorithm is likely to take many times longer to run than the initial allocation. If you mean readability, they could all be improved by adding a comment explaining what they are for.

Comment: Not that it affects speed, but why are you using `(1,length)` as opposed to just `(length,)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 = np.zeros((4, 1, len(pose07)-1))
```

EDIT:
ran some bench-marks

```py
def func1(inp):
    
    a = np.zeros([1, len(inp)])
    b = np.zeros([1, len(inp)])
    c = np.zeros([1, len(inp)])
    d = np.zeros([1, len(inp)])
    
    return 1
```

```py
def func2(inp):
    
    length = len(inp)

    a = np.zeros([1, length])
    b = np.zeros([1, length])
    c = np.zeros([1, length])
    d = np.zeros([1, length])
    
    return 1
```

```py
def func3(inp):
    
    a = np.zeros([1, len(inp)])
    b = np.copy(a)
    c = np.copy(a)
    d = np.copy(a)
    
    return 1
```

```py
def func4(inp):
    
    a, b, c, d = np.zeros([4, 1, len(inp)])
    
    return 1
```

```py
import perfplot

bench = perfplot.bench(
    n_range= range(1, 50),
    setup= lambda n: np.random.randint(100, size= [n]),
    kernels= [
        func1,
        func2,
        func3,
        func4
    ]
)

bench.show()
```

[image]

according to the benchmarks func2 (where length is stored in a variable first) seems to perform the best,

and try to avoid func 4, as pointed out by Paul Panzer in the comment below, func 4 can cause memory leaks

Comment: Depending on how `arr1,...,arr4` are going to be used, specifically, if one, say, lives much longer than the others, this may be a memory leak.

Comment: very reliable! Could you please run an extra experiment comparing the speed of  "a, b, c = [np.zeros(5) for _ in range(3)]"  according to stackoverflow.com/a/20860276/11667949  ?

Answer (score 0):

A nice concise way using multiple-assignment:

```
length=len(pose07)-1
dist_x, dist_y, rots_absolute, rots = 4 * [np.zeros(1, length)]
```